# Records Not Displaying in jquery.datatables using server side pagination processing

Tags: mvc.jquery.datatables

i am trying to get jquery.datatables working using server side processing and pagination. I used the following example article as a guide because its close to the version VS2017 that i am using-

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/filtering-jquery-data-table-server-side-using-mvc-and-entity-framework/

When I run the application i get the following error:

DataTables warning: table id=tblrtr - Requested unknown parameter 'Id' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

and an empty grid that shows 10 blank lines and the right page count.

I have debugged the code and it finds all the records and values, and indeed the finalresult variable does return the contents of the 10 rows- but they dont seem to make it to the datatable grid.

Here is the controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RTMGMTTest.Models;

namespace RTMGMTTest.Controllers
{
    public class ReportsToRecordsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly RTMGMTContext _context;

        public ReportsToRecordsController(RTMGMTContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: ReportsToRecords
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            //return View(await _context.ReportsToRecords.ToListAsync());
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult RTRList(DTParameters param)
        {

            int TotalCount = 0;
            var filtered = this.GetRTRFiltered(param.Search.Value, param.SortOrder, param.Start, param.Length, out TotalCount);

            var RTRList = filtered.Select(o => new ReportsToRecords()
            {

                Id = o.Id,
                ReportingId = o.ReportingId,
                Title = o.Title,
                Name = o.Name,
                ReportsToId = o.ReportsToId,
                EmployeeId = o.EmployeeId
            });



            DTResult<ReportsToRecords> finalresult = new DTResult<ReportsToRecords>
            {
                draw = param.Draw,
                data = RTRList.ToList(),
                recordsFiltered = TotalCount,
                recordsTotal = filtered.Count

            };

            return Json(finalresult);

        }
```

and

//for server side processing

```
public List<ReportsToRecords> GetRTRFiltered(string search, string sortOrder, int start, int length, out int TotalCount)
{


    var result = _context.ReportsToRecords.Where(p => (search == null 
        || (p.ReportingId != null && p.ReportingId.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
        || p.Title != null && p.Title.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
        || p.Name != null && p.Name.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
        || p.ReportsToId != null && p.ReportsToId.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
        || p.EmployeeId!= null && p.EmployeeId.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())
        ))).ToList();

    TotalCount = result.Count;

    result = result.Skip(start).Take(length).ToList();


    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "ReportingId":
            result = result.OrderBy(a => a.ReportingId).ToList();
            break;
        case "Title":
            result = result.OrderBy(a => a.Title).ToList();
            break;
        case "Name":
            result = result.OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList();
            break;
        case "ReportsToId":
            result = result.OrderBy(a => a.ReportsToId).ToList();
            break;
        case "EmployeeId":
            result = result.OrderBy(a => a.EmployeeId).ToList();
            break;
        default:
            result = result.AsQueryable().ToList();
            break;
    }
    return result.ToList();
}
```

The view page looks as follows:

```html
@model IEnumerable<RTMGMTTest.Models.ReportsToRecords>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#tblrtr')) {
            $('#tblrtr').dataTable().fnDestroy();
            $('#tblrtr').dataTable().empty();

        }

        var complete = $('#tblrtr').DataTable(
            {
                "serverSide": true,
                "destroy": true,
                "processing": true,
                "ajax":
                    {
                        url: "/ReportsToRecords/RTRList",
                        method: "POST"
                    },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Id"},
                    { "data": "ReportingId" },
                    { "data": "Title" },
                    { "data": "Name" },
                    { "data": "ReportsToId" },
                    { "data": "EmployeeId" }

                ]
            }

        );

        /// Following code is for filter input to apply filter only on Enter
        var itm = $("#tblrtr_filter input")

        itm.unbind();
        itm.keyup(function (e) {
            //enter or tab
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                complete.search(this.value).draw();
            }
        });


    });
</script>
<table class="table" id="tblrtr">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Id
            </th>
            <th>
                ReportingId
            </th>
            <th>
                Title
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                ReportsToId
            </th>
            <th>
                EmployeeId
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Does anyone know what would cause the data returned from the controller to not display and cause the resulting message? Thanks.

Comment: The cause is going to be an inconsistency between the Ajax being sent, and that what's expected by DataTables. It would help if you could post the Ajax into your message.

Comment: Thanks- turned out when i looked at json that the names of the variables in the columns area- needed to be lowercase for thefirst letter-                "columns": [
                    { "data": "id"},
                    { "data": "reportingId" },
                    { "data": "title" },
                    { "data": "name" },
                    { "data": "reportsToId" },
                    { "data": "employeeId" } . Now working- thanks again